# MailTo From Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mailto

I've got a link button which is used to build up a mailto from the contents of the page. What is the best way to launch it from javascript without opening a blank window or disturbing the window it's called from?

```
function Email()
{
    var sMailTo = "mailto:";
    var sBody = "";

    var alSelectedCheckboxes = new Array();
    $("input:checkbox[CheckBoxType=Email]:checked").each(function()
    {
        alSelectedCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
    });

    if (alSelectedCheckboxes.length > 0)
    {
        for (var i=0; i<alSelectedCheckboxes.length; i++)
        {
            sBody += alSelectedCheckboxes[i];
            sBody += "\n";
        }

        sMailTo += escape("<Insert Recipients Here>") +"?subject=" +escape("<Insert Subject Here>") +"&body=" +escape(sBody);
        window.location.href = sMailTo;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please select some results");
    }
}
```

The simple function is above. window.location.href doesn't work properly unless it's Firefox/Chrome (it redraws the page in IE8). I've also tried window.open(sMailTo, "_self") but again in IE8 this breaks the page that it's called from.

I'm sure this is a stupid question.... :-)

Thanks

Comment: Don't do this quietly on behalf of the user. Add it as a html link.

Comment: the javascript is executed by a link. The mailto contents are dynamic however so we need to do a little javascript first to figure out what to send as the body of the email

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think it's stupid at all!  This is a good start.  What I'd try next is just to create an actual link object in jquery, append it to the body, and then click() it.

```
//window.location.href = sMailTo;
$('<a href="' + sMailTo + '">click</a>').appendTo('body').click().remove();
```

Should work as long as the escape() function you're using gets rid of all of the quotes and correctly encodes the html.

But I have to say, this could be hard to get *just* right.  If it still doesn't work, I'd recommend doing it server-side where the link POSTS all of the html needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery, then you can easily create an element based on the markup you build (refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent) for an example)  and then invoke the link's click event by simply doing this:

```
element.click();
```

Comment: Safari would prevent from allowing to fire the click() event !