# Need help learning ajax, grabbing data from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I have an ajax script, which I kinda understand, but still need some extra help.

```
$('.images').click(function(){
    var imageId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(imageName);
    $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "imageData.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {getImageId: imageId},
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert(imageId);
                $("#images_"+imageId).html(data);
            }
        });
    //$('#images_'+imageId).toggle();

});
```

I have that code, it goes to this imageData.php file

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET)){
    $images = "";
    $path = 'img/';
    $imageId = $_GET['getImageId'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE iID = '".$imageId."'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $images .= $path.$row['images'];
}
    $json = json_encode($images);
?>
<img src='<?php echo $json;?>'/>

    <?php
}
    ?>
```

Why does it output error when I try to echo a string from $images, but it outputs correctly when I do `echo $imageId;`? I'm trying to output something from mysql, but not trying to output just the id.

Need help please, thank you

Comment: Do you get that error when jQuery ajax returns you the value ? Do a `echo json_encode($images);`

Comment: It doesn't return a value, i just get the error. I tried doing the json_encode($images); I don't get an error anymore, however, I don't get a successful alert either.

Comment: I'm not sure if json can be alerted try console.log instead. Does firebug console response is empty?

Comment: oh it works, it doesn't alert. but i can see if i double click on the object, it shows the string. But I have one more concern if you can answer it: I'm trying to output an image, but how do I do this? I have edited my code if you can take a look at it. Thank you for your help

Comment: I want to try to echo that `<img...` is this possible?

Comment: Why are you using `json_encode`? What is the content of `$row['images']`? Currently you are creating a string of whatever and set this as the src of the **one** image. Could it be that you want to output more than one image? Does the query return more than one image from the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need use `json_encode` here, there is not data that needs to be in JSON format. There is also no reason to loop over the result set, if the query only returns one image.

Try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['getImageId'])) {
    $path = '';
    $imageId = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['getImageId']); // SQL injection!
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT images FROM images WHERE iID = '".$imageId."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($row) {
        $path = 'img/' . $row['images'];
    }
}
?>
<?php if($path): ?>
    <img src='<?php echo $path;?>'/>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If the `iID` is actually an integer, you need to omit the single quotes in the query.

You also have to change the `dataType` from `json` to `html`, as **you are returning an image tag (HTML) and not JSON**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "imageData.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {getImageId: imageId},
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#images_"+imageId).html(data);
    }
});
```

---

Another option is to return only text (the link) and create the images on the client side:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['getImageId'])) {
    $path = '';
    $imageId = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['getImageId']); // SQL injection!
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT images FROM images WHERE iID = '".$imageId."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($row) {
        echo 'img/' . $row['images'];
    }
}
?>
```

And in JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "imageData.php",
    dataType: "text",
    data: {getImageId: imageId},
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#images_"+imageId).html('<img src="' + data + '" />');
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, changing `$("#images_"+imageId).html('<img src="' + data + '" />');` helped. Also, I'm trying to add toggle, which I did this `$("#images_"+imageId).toggle().html('<img src="' + data + '" />');` but it toggles when i double click it for the first time, not single click it. any idea why it does this? Thank you

Comment: also, if you can help me. if I echo more than one thing, say i want to echo also `echo $row['userid']` how do I separate these two "images and userid" from data in ajax?

Answer (score 1):

As you may get many images because you use while loop you probably want to do this like so:

in php:

```
$x = 0;
$another = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $another[$x] = $path.$row['images'];
    $x++;
}

echo json_encode($another);
```

and in jquery (in your success callback):

```
$.each(data, function(i, v){
    // Do the image inserting to the DOM here v is the path to image
    $('#somelement').append('<img src="'+v+'"');
});
```

Comment: when you say many images do you mean because append() keeps adding multiple same objects?

Comment: Well as you did while loop in php i assumed you retrieve multiple images sometimes. And append() will keep adding images in loop till it has added all of them.

Answer (score 0):

For outputing an image you must set `src` attribute of the image tag, if you already have one, or you can create it on the fly. See here how to do that > [jQuery document.createElement equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent)