# Facebook likebox dark color scheme is unreadable

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-likebox

FB Like Box "Dark" Scheme now displays BLACK text on BLACK background [used to be white text]

see http://vitgravitas.com

i tried to modify the css of class .messageBody using js but even that isn't working for some reasons.

Any idea how to fix this. I can't shift to light color scheme as it doesn't suits my site template..

Comment: Did you mean the "Like" text ? But its in light background + dark text (navy blue)

Comment: I can't see where you are referencing on your site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haha, yah that's a bug in the Facebook Like Box.

You cannot style an iframe with an outside page. You need to inject a stylesheet into the iframe itself a-la @DrJokepu. [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Just make a stylesheet:

```
body {
    color: white !important;
}
```

and inject it without jQuery ([it's faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent)):

```
var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
cssLink.href = "style.css"; 
cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
cssLink.type = "text/css"; 
frames['frame'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
```

assuming you give the `<fb:likebox>` the id `frame`.

Good luck!