# Creating Color Gallery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, gallery, append

I am trying to make Colors' Gallery, but I cannot achieve it.
[**Here is what I've done so far.**](http://jsfiddle.net/FoxKiD/8USqU/)
I want to try, when the user clicks button, `li` appended to `ul` and this is where the mess starts. I thought after I append `li`, the `background-color` would've applied to `li` itself but it instead applied to `ul`. Could you help me pls, cuz I am newbie and also don't blame me for my English if I have mistakes. English is my **third** language, trying to explain as hard as I can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code check it out http://jsfiddle.net/8USqU/5/

This part is looking wrong.

```
$('#gallery').append('<li></li>').css('background', storedHex);
```

I changed to

```
$("<li>").css('background-color', storedHex).appendTo($('#gallery'));
```

Actually you can use `background-color` instead of `background`. Because `background` selector can take lots of property, but all you need is `background-color`

Comment: You need to make that <li /> to have a self-enclosing element added.

Comment: Not necessarily. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent there is not much difference between them.

Comment: That's not it. if you use your method then you're using the HTML way. If you use self-closing tags you're using XHTML valid markup.

Answer (score 2):

You need to simply change the order of operations.

Instead of targeting the Gallery, adding the element, and trying to change the css.

We'll create the element, target the Element's CSS, then append that element to #gallery.

Have a look at the jsfiddle below to see the change in action.

> http://jsfiddle.net/8USqU/4/