# $(this).dialog is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-ui-dialog

...or Why `$(this).dialog()` fails in Firefox when using dynamic HTML?

I have a a click event that opens a jQuery modal dialog box on a web page, and it is working fine in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox.

Here is the pertinent code:

```
var dialogId = 'uniqueName-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
var dialogDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", dialogId);

dialogDiv.load(this.href, function () {
    var dialog = $(this).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    ...
});
```

In Firefox 11, `$(this).dialog({ autoOpen: false })` fails with the following error message:

> $(this).dialog is not a function

But in IE 9 an Chrome 17 everything is working fine. Any clue why that is?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my `document.ready` function where the code above was. I removed it to simplify things. ALERT A is occuring before ALERT B. ALERT A says `[object Object]`. ALERT B occurs when I click on a link and it says `'undefined'`.

```
$(function () {

    alert($.ui);    // ALERT A

    // Wire up the click event of any dialog links
    $('.dialogLink').live('click', function () {
        alert($.ui);    // ALERT B
        return false;
    });
});
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Now that I pin pointed where the problem was coming from I rephrased my question and posted the minimal code to reproduce the original problem here: [Why is FF on OS X losing jQuery-UI in click event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900989/why-is-ff-loosing-jquery-ui-in-click-event-handler)

Comment: Can you debug with console.log or a simple alert to check if jquery is working fine? Also if its jquery UI, use firebug to check if it loads fine in ff!

Comment: @MarshallMathews: jQuery is working fine, since dialogDiv is initialized fine with $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", dialogId). I checked this with firebug. How would you go about checking whether jQuery-UI loads fine with Firebug?

Comment: `console.log("This explains the dialog method: " + $.ui.dialog)` if false, then maybe UI isn't loaded right

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you creating a div with `$(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", dialogId);`? Why not just use `$('<div></div>').attr("id", dialogId);`?

Comment: Works fine in FF11 in a fiddle when loading from "/echo/html".  Must be something else going on in the code.

Comment: @j08691: Because of posts like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent) saying that is more efficient.

Comment: Might as well rewrite it all in pure JS if you want efficiency.

Comment: @j08691 Well, jQuery is very useful. Writing everything would not be efficient in terms of my work throughput. However, if in suche instances I have the choice between 2 ways of doing things that lead to the same result, I will choose the more efficient of the two.

Comment: @KyleMacey I added your console.log() line right at the beginning of my dialogDiv.Load() method, and I got "$.ui is undefined" as output. However, I also put the same console.log() command right under the line where I include jQuery-UI 1.8.18, and there it worked fine. It is also executed before the former consol.log(). I really don't understand why jquery-ui is "becoming" undefined.

Comment: An error in your Javascript is most likely causing a break in propagation.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bit of a syntax/chaining issue if I'm not mistaken:

```
var dialogId = 'uniqueName-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
//var dialogDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", dialogId);
//dialogDiv equals the attribute 'id'
//try and console.log(dialogDiv) right here. what I think you want is:

var dialogDiv = $("<div />");
dialogDiv.attr("id", dialogId).load(this.href, function () {
    var dialog = $(this).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    ...
});
```

I also don't think this is the correct way to initialize what you're trying to do... can you describe what's going on, on your page?

you may think about doing something like this:

```
var dialogId = 'uniqueName-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
//Build some HTML here in the dialog div, or in a string.
theHTML = $('#'+dialogId).html() || "<p>This is a string of HTML</p>";
$('body').on('click', ".button" function () {
    console.log($.ui);
    $.dialog({autoOpen:true, html: theHTML})
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I am loosing jQuery-UI in the click event handler when using Firefox. My code is running fine with Google Chrome and with IE. I don't think the changes you are proposing will fix the issue I am trying to solve.

Comment: Try putting the $.ui in that piece, I don't have ff11 but it workes for me in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score -1):

The problem was with a Firefox Add-On. I started Firefox in safe mode, and now everything is working fine. I tried to identify which Add-On caused the problem, and I restarted Firefox with various Add-Ons turned on or off, but I can't seem to be able to reproduce the problem now.