# Generate html from array in a better way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have an array of Customer structures and I need to generate HTML from it.

Currently I do something like this:

```
jQuery.each(customers, function(index, item) {
     html =+ "<tr custID='" + item.ID + "'><td>" + item.Name + "</td><td>" + item.City + "</td></tr>";  
});
```

The issue here is that I manually add the custID attribute.
I believe the cool way to do this would be using jQuery's Data function.

But how would I use it in this scenario?

Comment: just google for javascript template engines or MVVM javascript frameworks.

Comment: I've used http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/ in the past. Works pretty well.

Comment: It would be cool to use a template engine and not generate html by concatenating strings in js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elegant way is not to append those html tags as if they are text, but create element using

```
document.createElement("tr");
```

you can modify its attributes and then append it to the html file.

Read more here:

[jQuery document.createElement equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent)

Answer (score 1):

Just prefix the attribute with `data-`:

```
jQuery.each(customers, function(index, item) {
  html += "<tr data-custID='" + item.ID + "'><td>" + item.Name + "</td><td>" + item.City + "</td></tr>";  
});
```

Now you can access the data using the methods in jQuery.

(I changed the non-existing `=+` operator to `+=`. Guess it was just a typo in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use data grid i think it is much cooler than manually creating tables. But in your case you have to use append() function.

Here is good examples:
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/add-table-row-using-jquery-and.html
http://api.jquery.com/append/