# Creating form elements at runtime in JSP

Tags: xml, forms, jsp, struts2, tiles

Hi I am creating an application where for each user form elements being displayed could be different 
(type of element, number of element, label of the form element, order of appearance : all these could differ from user to user).

I am fetching these user prefernece from DB.

I was hoping to implement some technique/tool/method so that I could create the JSP to be shown to the user at runtime from centralized framework 
(I want to reuse the same component for creating JSP for the users).

I am thinking some XML transformation using XSLT, but not sure how to do it or whether that is the best approach.

Any suggestions?

PS : I am using Struts + Spring Framework.

Comment: Interesting. I would go with jquery for creating dynamic elements

Comment: Could you direct me to a example? Would it be possible to create prepopulated fields, dropdowns?

Comment: What I meant was, if you are planning to do it on client side then you could use jquery to create dynamic elements [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent).

Comment: I want to do it on server side. That way prepopulating the fields and managing the whole setup would be efficient.

Comment: I think XML/XSLT is NOT the way to go (having had to maintain such beasts in the past - anyone remember Cocoon?). I would start "simple" and simply code in JSP with regular logic. If you are getting really fancy (different ordering and placement of fields, etc), then I would look at a client-side approach as others have suggested. There are quite a few frameworks/tools to do this with.

Comment: Could you suggest any framework/tool?

Comment: well u can simply put ur <form></form> tag inside a jsp conditions like if else it would work perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enough R&D i have come up with the following approach.
Get the user preferences in Java object(in list/map format).
This object should contain the label name, order, input type, default value etc.
Then transform this Java object to a JSON object( using any lib like GSON, Jackson etc).

Next parse this JSON object in javascript using javascript/jquery and then parse the thus formed JSON object to create the form fields(by iterating ovet the JSON object)

Comment: is there any performance issue, if you create dynamic html using json in clientside? which approach is better, creating dynamic page from client side or server side?

Answer (score 0):

If you want do this on server side then maybe you can do something with `Apache Tiles` http://tiles.apache.org/. There is a runtime composition API as well http://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/tutorial/advanced/runtime.html.

Comment: I want to have different set of form element for each user. If go for tiles I ll have to create a tile per user. That wouldnt be very useful.

Comment: You could create tile per `some reusable component`.

Comment: Thanks...But i m still skeptical..Do you have implemented examples for the same??

Comment: Take a look at tiles tutorials there are examples how to fetch tiles definitions from database and how to manipulate tiles at runtime.