# jQuery HTML element selector clarification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I would like to know what is the difference between these two jQuery selectors:

- `$("span")`
- `$("<span>")`

I know that the former is used to select *all* elements of the provided HTML tag type in the page (which is specified in the [jQuery Element Selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)). I am not sure what the latter selector does.

Apologies if this question is a duplicate. If so, please kindly post the URI of the duplicated question.

Comment: Explained in `jQUery()` method docs. 2 sections to doc, covering both cases http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first goes out and finds all existing `span` elements. The second creates a new `span` element, wrapped in a jQuery object.

```
$("span").css("color", "red"); // Make all current <span> elements red
$("<span>").text("Foo").appendTo("body"); // Create new <span>, add to <body>
```

#### Optional Second Arguments

Both can take a second argument as well. In the case of the first, the second argument is the context:

```
$("span", "#foo"); // Becomes $("#foo").find("span");
```

In the case of the second, the second argument is an object-literal consisting of properties:

```
$("<span>", { 
    "html": "This is the HTML", 
    "class": "newSpan"
}).appendTo("body");
```

This is similar to calling the individual methods to set html and attributes:

```
$("<span>")
    .html("This is the HTML")
    .attr("class", "newSpan")
    .appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("span") //Finds all span
$("<span>") //Create a span element
```

**[See this answer : jQuery document.createElement equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent)**