# create dynamic check box and button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Method

```
   function CreateButton(tag, isVisible, text, event) {
        var elem;
        elem = $(document.createElement('input'));
        elem.type = tag;
        elem.prop('value', text);
        elem.css('display', isVisible == 'true' ? '' : 'none');
        elem.click(event);
        return elem;
    }
```

caller

```
 function DrawButtons(mode) {
        var text = mode == 'true' ? 'Cancel' : 'Close';
        $('#fdEitDetail').append(CreateButton('button', mode, 'Save & Close', save));
        $('#fdEitDetail').append(CreateButton('button', mode, 'Save & mark Completed', mark));
        $('#fdEitDetail').append(CreateButton('button', mode, text, close));
}
```

The method is supposed to be creating button , but it is creating text box.

One of the other methods say

```
function CheckBox(tagName, isEditable)
{
 elem = $(document.createElement('input'));
            elem.type = tagName;
            elem.attr('checked', text ? 'checked' : '');
}
```

caller

```
$('#dvCheck').append(CheckBox('checkbox', mode));
```

it is creating text box. Any help??

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8S7st/

Comment: @tilda it is working but is pure old school javascript, i was following this link for performance too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent/268520#268520 can't we do some thing with jquery rather than doing the fiddle way though it is working perfectly

Comment: You posted your code in js so I thought that's what you want. Try to transform it to jquery, put it in fiddle and please post it here to see where's the problem.

Comment: @tilda there is no problem in code like error , it is just that inplace of checkbox and button only input type text is being created by my code

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to create jQuery Object ( $(document.....)) ?
`$(document.createElement('input')) ==> Make jQuery Object` .
To create jQuery Object you can use simply $("")
Example:

```
$(“<div>”).attr(“id”,”div-source”)
.addClass(‘highlight’)
.css(“color”,”blue”)
.on(“click”,function(){}
);
```

In your case , you can use

```
$("<input>").attr("type",tagName).attr('checked', text ? 'checked' : '');
```

Hopt it helps you

Comment: after using the above code it has created the checkbox but it is coming checked always though the value of text is false.

Comment: function CheckBox(tagName, text)
{
var elem = $("<input>").attr("type",tagName).attr('checked', text ? 'checked' : '');
return elem; 
};
you can use like this and call CheckBox('datetime','checked');