# I have Problems with inserting div in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to inserting div in Jquery, like in the example below. It doesn't work.

Jquery:

```
$('<div />', {
    $('<img />', { "src": "/Pages/Images/calendar.png").addClass('image').appendTo($div);
    $('<input/>', { "type": "text", "class": "ctb" }).addClass('ctb').appendTo($div);
    }).addClass('sto').appendTo($div);
```

The output I want is like the image below:

[image]

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/44/)

Comment: have you seen the console and tried to fix the issues in it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't append the elements like that you must do this

```
$('<div>', {
    "class": "sto"
}).append('<img />', {
    "src": "/Pages/Images/calendar.png",
    "class": "image"
}).append('<input/>', {
    "type": "text",
    "class": "ctb"
}).appendTo($div);
```

Comment: I have test it, works fine. But the problem is that a input field appears on the card. I don't want it. I want it like the image above. What am I able to do, to fix it? I have a demo with your part of code: http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/46/

Answer (score 1):

You didn't create $(div) yet. You should do it like

```
var div = $('<div></div>');
$(div).append(...);
```

Btw, the best method to create element is

```
document.createElement();
```

[jQuery document.createElement equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent)

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot of syntax errors.

I changed you part to:

```
$('<div />').append($('<img src="/Pages/Images/calendar.png" class="image" />')).appendTo($div);
$('<input type="text" class="ctb sto" />').appendTo($div);
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/45/

Comment: But can You help me to fix it to look like the image above?