# Open pop-up box automatic with different ID in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I use a pop-up jQuery box for pop up window but when I use it on same page for multiple pop-up boxes then it only one not for all because my id is same on all button I use for pop-up.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

```
    ;(function($) {

     // DOM Ready
    $(function() {

        // Binding a click event
        // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
        $('#full-pop').bind('click', function(e) {

            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            e.preventDefault();

            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $('#full-detail-box').bPopup();

        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

and here is pop-up

```
<div id="full-detail-box">this is pop up</div>
```

Comment: you want multiple pop up boxes? How many pop up boxes do you want?

Comment: 25 pop-up on one page with using php while loop

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle???

Comment: you can use query to create other divs for your other popups. In other words, don't hard-code the divs, but make them programmatically…  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent

Comment: @Kiranramchandran this is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sac050/3nLYs/

Comment: @Will Newton this is not my question..

Comment: @Sam what is your question?

Comment: @WillNewton see my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sac050/3nLYs/2/
and here i use pop-up box multitime with same id but this is not work

Comment: why do you have 3 divs with the same id?

Comment: @WillNewton here i use php while loop for automatic generate new div so i use one id,i use it for show different user detail, i want use pop-up box different with different value like when in button it show first user detail and when i click on second button it show second user detail

Comment: You should never reuse the same ID on a page. Use class names.

Comment: @JordanThompson i try it  but this not properly work you hoave any solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

**JS**

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    $('body').append("<div id='full-detail-box"+i+"' class='full-detail-box'>"+(i+1)+" User this is my pop-up window that is opem multi timewith different value </div><br/><a class='btn-pro' data-id='full-detail-box"+i+"' href='#'>Full Detail</a>")
}

 $('.btn-pro').bind('click', function(e) {


            e.preventDefault();

            var id=$(this).data('id');

            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $('#'+id).bPopup();

       });
```

Instead Of this

```
$('#full-pop').bind('click', function(e) {

            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            e.preventDefault();

            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $('#full-detail-box').bPopup();

        });
```

**[UPDATED DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/4btzA/4/)**

Comment: thanks dude
but it it show same value for both button
when i click 2 button it show 2nd user detail not show 1st user detail
i use this for show user detail with pop-up

Comment: thanks a lot dude but can i automatic generate div here like full-detail-box, full-detail-box1, full-detail-box2, full-detail-box3, and many times

Comment: html added dynamically at document ready in a for loop $('body').append("<div id='full-detail-box"+i+"' class='full-detail-box'>"+(i+1)+" User this is my pop-up window that is opem multi timewith different value </div><br/><a class='btn-pro' data-id='full-detail-box"+i+"' href='#'>Full Detail</a>")

Comment: but it is show same detail for all user, i want show different detail with help of php

Comment: well i'm not an expert in php.. i just show you the sample javascript code to do this. you can append the content dynamically in the div by taking it from database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are passing the same id repeatedly, which just opens the same popup over and over again.  If you want multiple popups you need multiple DOM nodes to trigger a popup on.

Comment: how i do this @moliveira

Comment: You could create the popup elements programmatically as Will Newton suggested above. I think something like   $("<div id='full-detail-box'>this is pop up</div>").bPopup(); would work - but that is only one of many ways to accomplish that. The important part is that you are calling the popup function on different dom elements each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using user detail, why not just append a unique ID!? You can easily add, in PHP, or w/e the ID of the user at the end of the class name `id="full-detail-box-xx"` where XX  is the ID of the user.

Then you simply use the button with the SAME id in the function to call the user, like `$('#full-detail-' + id).click(function(){ bPopup('#full-detail-box' + id); });`

If you are using PHP you can write the ID to a JS array, or something. I'm not sure how you system is set up.