# Texts are not truncating properly when the hyper link is added in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have developed the code such that the text should get truncate after 200 characters ,But it is not working as expected when a hyperlink is added in between the text . In this case , the texts are truncating even before 200 characters .

I have attached both the screenshots  , 1. texts are truncating properly and 2.hyperlink added [where](http://i.stack.img) texts are not truncating correctly .

Please let me know what can be done here to make the text truncate properly after 200 characters when the hyper link is added .

Any help would be appreciated !!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmbf0.png)ur.com/7XSjr.png

```
enter code here

Java script :
var MAX_CHARS = 200;
  var ELLIP = String.fromCharCode(8230);
  function truncateIdeaText (str) {
    if (str.length < MAX_CHARS) return str;
    return str.substr(0, MAX_CHARS) + ' ' + ELLIP;
  }

  var tagIdx = 0;
  /* Creates a single block (closeup)*/
  function createCloseup (idea, pageNr) {
    var d = jQuery('<div>', {'class': 'ideasblock'});
    // the bellow replace of /ideas/ to /Ideas/ id to get arround the ideas rewrite file
    d.append("<a class='ideas-link' href='"+browserUrl+"/"+idea.roomId+"/"+"'><img src='" + idea.image + "' width='512' data-page-nr='" + pageNr + "' onclick=javascript:fnSubmit('"+idea.roomId+"'); />" +
    "<h2 class='ideasHeadLine'>" + idea.headLine + "</h2>" +
    "<div class='ideasdate'>" + idea.startDate + "</div>" +
    "<p class='ideasPara'>" + truncateIdeaText(idea.text) + "</p>"); 

CSS : 

a.ideas-link {
        color: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
    }
    a.ideas-link:hover  .ideasHeadLine {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }   

.ideasPara{
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        text-align: left;
        left: 0px;
        width: 512px; 
        display:block;
        font-family: 'Verdana';
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #333333;
        line-height: 18px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution (with minimal code changes) in my opinion could be this -
Define a few more variables (i.e. linkTagBaseLength, linkHrefLength etc.)
then use a boolean variable to figure out if the link exists or not.

The use this code inside the function `truncateIdeaText()` together with `MAX_CHARS`.

**It is however unclear** if you wish to show the link as a code on screen (see my above solution).

If you wish on the other hand to add a link to the span as html elements
I would suggest you create the elements you need first (define them in local variables for better control of the program) and use then use jquery's [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function.

([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent) for code example).

Or you can always use Javascript's [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) function.