# translation of vanilla JavaScript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is a JS function:

I'd like to update this so it uses jQuery but I am having difficulty figuring out how to translate it.

```js
function pathContents(fileList) {
    var list = document.createElement('ul');
    for (file in fileList) {
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fileList[file]));
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
    return list;
}
```

UPDATE:
Removing the call to pathContents() and replacing it with Malvolio's code - this is the browser output -

[image]

Why isn't it displaying the data as list items in an unordered list?

Comment: Why converting it into jQuery? What's wrong with that code snippet? If you want to create a jQuery object, pass the returned value to jQuery: `$( pathContents(fileList) )` and done :)

Comment: Don't fix anything that is not broken

Comment: Why?  Vanilla JS is more performant than jQuery.

Comment: Because I'm trying to learn jQuery and doing a translation is a useful exercise in the learning process.

Comment: JQuery isn't something "else". It's still Javascript. So translating "from JS to JQuery" doesn't make much sense. You're just rewriting it to use a Javascript library.

Comment: @ryanlutgen - well, you could write AJAX in js without jQuery but it wouldn't be as short, maintainable, readable and configurable easily as jQuery. but generally it's true, but not even 90%. much less, jquery is very very performant and in many cases performance isn't as important as readability

Comment: Note that your update exposes a misunderstanding of  what the code @Malvollio posted is doing - this will not work - you're not going to return a list but a function.. That code is meant to **replace** your `pathContents` function, not go inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery equivalent "all-the-way" would be:

```
function pathContents(fileList) {
    var $list = $('<ul/>');
    $.each(fileList, function () {
        $('<li/>').text(this).appendTo($list);
    });
    return $list;
}
```

The use of `this` inside `$.each` is often seen in jQuery code, but it is cleaner to use the function arguments instead:

```
    $.each(fileList, function (_, file) {
        $('<li/>').text(file).appendTo($list);
    });
```

But the pure JavaScript way really is not that bad. For one, you cannot beat the performance of it.

Comment: is the `text(fileList[file])` will eliminate problems that I'm fixing with regex?

Comment: The Console shows ReferenceError: file is not defined.

Comment: btw, in your code `fileList[file]` will be `undefined`... You've forgot to add function parameter, like this: `function (file) { ... }` when you passing callback to the `$.each()`

Comment: @spirit: Ah yes, the best way is to use `this`: that really is how jQuery works. Thanks. Now the code really looks nice

Comment: @spirit, I missed your first comment: yes the text method takes care of this, as it comes down to assigning to the `textContent` DOM property, which does not interpret text as HTML, but as .... plain text.

Comment: I disagree with using `this` in the `$.each`. Essentially you just opt to use a variable that you can't name instead of one that you can. jQuery doesn't "work that way", in fact in 90% of cases in jQuery, you can use a named parameter instead of `this` - the fact that people insist on using the context parameter is just bad culture.

Comment: Also, you don't need closing `/` in the element factories - that's another case of people just seeing bad code in blogs and going with it. Check the jQuery source, it doesn't care if there's a slash there or not.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer, closing html tag is not bad code. it just **valid xml**.

Comment: The jQuery documentation seems to give [no preference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements) for adding the slash or even the complete closing tag, while SO shows that [everyone has their opinion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/268520/5459839) on it. ;-)

Comment: I see your point about `this`, @GeorgeMauer, although the function argument of interest is the second one, so it would look like `function (_, file)`, which ... well, ... is a bit of a pity.

Comment: @trincot yes, you're correct, there's no preference  in the docs - that's why I said [check the jquery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/var/rsingleTag.js). It basically does a regex that ignores terminating slashes. There's no preference expressed over not doing `$('<ul//////>`) either, its just ignored.

Comment: Why is function argument of interest the second one?  I got lost on that part.  What is the first argument?  I see in the code the first argument is represented as _ but don't understand why.

Comment: The first argument is de index in the array, and the second is the value of the array element at that index. So if you would name the first argument `i` you could write `fileList[i]`, but with the second argument, the same is written by just using that argument: `file`.

Comment: @knot22 so basically a long time ago, the jQuery team screwed up - when you're using `$.each` it would make sense to have it be `$.each(array, function(value, index) { })` which is how it works everywhere else, but they screwed up and inverted the two parameters. `_` is just a valid variable name that by convention we know to indicate "this isn't used". (Technically btw the jQuery team didn't screw up - they did this before it was conventional everywhere else).

Comment: Yep, I suppose you could phrase it like that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you can try following :):

```
function pathContents(fileList) {
    var list = $('<ul />');
    for (file in fileList) {
        list.append($('<li />').text(fileList[file]));
    }
    return list;
}
```

or you can `return list.html()`;

And yes, as many users mentioned, you will have some performance loss compared to pure `javascript`

Comment: Let's just hope there is no ampersand or less-than sign somewhere in that file list.

Comment: Or a file named `<script>location.replace("http://scammer.ru")</script>`

Comment: Nah, that way lies madness.  You may _think_ you have caught every case, but you'll find out when someone hacks your site.  Use the library-provided tools, like `.text()`.

Comment: @Malvolio, and you really think that giving me -1 is a good idea??? So why you didn't give -1 to *vsync* than? he is not using anything at all =)

Comment: Just because I didn't see vsync's answer.  Any answer that encourages _security flaws_ is a bad answer.  Your answer, as amended, isn't terrible, but much better to use proper libraries.

Comment: @Malvolio, ok. Now what's the problem with my code? Is that that I'm using `for` and not an `$.each()`?

Comment: _Personally_ I prefer `.map` or `$.each`, but `in` is not a security hole (the way constructing HTML from input would be).  Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The modern version of your function would be

```
let pathContents =
    fileList => 
         $('<ul/>').append(fileList.map(file => $('<li/>').text(file)));
```

This version uses jQuery to create and append to DOM objects, the fat-arrow notation for functions, and the `.map` method on lists.  It doesn't rely on the unreliable `in` operator and avoids the [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) exploit.

I kept your function and variable names, but I think you should consider more descriptive names.

Comment: In the console it says TypeError: fileList.map is not a function.

Comment: @knot22 then either you're using a [really really old browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=map) or `fileList` is not an array as your code implies.

Comment: Browser is Firefox 47.0.

Comment: @knot22 so your code implied that `fileList` as an array, but if you're on 47 it is not. That is why Malvolio said to use `map`. You can instead do `$.map(fileList, file => $('<li>').text(file))` which will operate just on the values of `fileList` which I assume is an object. If it still doesn't do what you want it to do, you might want to specify what type `fileList` is

Comment: Strange...I was sure it was an array.  I will go look.

Comment: The output from the parsed JSON is {"fileList":["Queries","Scripts","Sprocs","Tables","Views"]}

Comment: @knot22 open up the console and check what `Array.isArray(fileList)` gives you

Comment: I added that as the first line of the pathContents() function but nothing appeared in the Console.  Also tried putting it in the function that calls pathContents() and nothing showed in the Console either.  Evidently I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You need to add `console.log(Array.isArray(fileList))` if it's in the program itself.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not being very specific - you  might want to take a minute and watch a video on how to use the debugger to halt code execution at a certain point so that you can look around (though fair warning - in my experience the Firefox debugger is one of the worst out there and frequently just plain doesn't work)

Comment: Made the update recommended by Malvolio but the Console still shows nothing.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer -- are you talking about Firebug?  My experience with it has been entirely positive.

Comment: I switched over to Chrome and then `console.log(Array.isArray(fileList)` worked fine.  It is returning true.

Comment: @Malvolio both Firebug and the built-in one. Nearly threw my computer out the window a few years ago after the 50th time it failed to stop on a breakpoint or expose a variable in console, or swallowed a console.log. It's happened to several coworkers too. Might depend on the Operating System though. I like Firefox in theory, but they are by far the most frustrating experience with browser bugs I've had since IE6 days (try doing anything with building up custom iframes). Anyways, waay off topic.

Comment: @knot22 then `fileList.map` should definitely exist and should definitely be a function - are you sure that you copied the original code correctly?

Comment: I will edit my original post so it's visible.  I was not sure if this code was supposed to be placed in the pathContents() function or if it was meant to be implemented some other way.

Comment: @knot22 this code *is* the `pathContents` function - note the `let pathContents = ..` - that creates a function and puts it into a `pathContents` variable. Everything else is the function body using es6 arrow functions. Which by the way won't work in Firefox 47 or Chrome < 51. You're coming to Javascript at a weird time. The language saw its largest update of syntax ever last year and many people still don't know how to use the new sytnax, what it means, nor which browsers natively support it (and how to get around that with transpilers).

Comment: Ah ha!  OK, I replaced the line that called pathContents() to the code exactly posted by @Malvolio above and the browser output is nearly there.  It's just not being displayed as list items.  I'll edit my original post with a screen shot so you can see the output now.

Answer (score -1):

For better performance only parse the HTML string at the very end:

```js
function pathContents(fileList) {
    var ul = '<ul>';
    for( var file of fileList )
        ul += `<li>${file}</li>`;
    ul += '</ul>';
    
    return $.parseHTML(ul);
;
}

console.log( pathContents([1,2,3])[0].outerHTML )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or as simple as:

```
function pathContents(fileList) {
    var ul = '<ul><li>' + fileList.join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>';

    return $.parseHTML(ul);
}
```

---

By using `$.parseHTML` the parsed output will be stripped of any `<script>` tags. If you do want to keep them, pass `true` as the second argument for that method. See [further discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24816/104380) about this.

> Please be *careful* when creating DOM from javascript: make sure the
>   input is sanitized 
> (does not contain any malicious code).

Comment: That could even be a one-liner :)

Comment: but what about some special characters? =) look at my answer

Comment: Should '</ul' be '</ul>'?

Comment: @knot22 - yeah thanks, fixed. what about special characters? works good with `pathContents(['<b>a&b</b>',2,3]);`

Comment: @trincot - one liner it is :)

Comment: this will produce an invalid `html` from the validator point of view =)

Comment: @spirit - the validator can go validate itself ;) anyway, build tools should convert such things into HTML entities automatically

Comment: PLEASE DON'T DO THIS! This is a cross-site-scripting attack vector. Your site and your users will get hacked. I agree with the concept you're trying to portray, but people will see this and stick this in their sites without further research. Either put a hard disclaimer on it or delete the answer.

Comment: I'm with George.  Don't [bury dragon's teeth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_teeth_(mythology)), especially not pursuing an illusory or unneeded performance enhancement.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer, How?

Comment: @JonSG -- a file named `<script>location.replace("http://scammer.ru")</script>` will have an... undesired effect.

Comment: @JonSG suppose `file` is something that a user can define at some point? What happens when they set it to `<script>alert("You've been hacked!")</script>`? What happens when someone views the page? (Actually that exact thing wouldn't work but you get the idea I hope...also rather than pop up an error how about stealing authentication cookies?) You can find out more by looking up how XSS works. Any time you concatenate strings (and then set `innerHTML`) you're going to have this prolem. That's why using the `text` method (`textContent` property in vanillajs) is highly recommended.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - WHAT are you talking about? are you kidding me??? the question is about looping an array and returning a jQuery unordered list element. that is all, it's something done everywhere, for a decade. nobody even said that the OP's code is even connected to the internet. I have been downvoted unfairly.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - it's not the responsibility and the scope of this thread to deal with imaginary risks which might exist or not, that is for another separate discussion. a simple question got a simple answer, to the point, and there is no "law" saying an answer must cover every possible scenario. I do the implement the above code for years in internal protected systems where nothing can happen, and there is protection layer also which will prevent such things as you've mentioned, which if completely transparent.

Comment: @vsync Like I said - the concept that you're conveying I actually agree with. It's just a little irresponsible to put code with obvious security bugs and no warning on here. You *know* how the internet works - people will find, copy, paste. If you edit a disclaimer into your answer that this is a security issue and exactly when it is/is not a problem I would gladly upvote.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - (1) nobody said the array that is being transformed into a list element is of any malicious content, so you could assume your unbased assumption on ANY array-related answer in here which transforms it to HTML, which is how templates work (2) the title of this page and the manner of the question has nothing to do with injecting any scripts. it is highly improbable that doing standard array iteration and constructing HTML will harm anyone. it's is the basic thing done by countless everyday. (like underscore templates/Jade and so on), stop making an elephant out of a mouse.

Comment: My answer is not different (and better) than the chosen one and was bashed unfairly.

Comment: Templates do *not* simply concatenate - nearly all the ones I know have built-in anti-xss scrubbing devices and check them regularly against OWASP. If you really think XSS isn't that big a deal, go install the BeefProject VM and spend 15 minutes playing with a real hacker tool - cross site scripting is terrifying in what it can do. Yes, many people do this, and many get hacked. But yes, I agree - it wasn't in the scope of the question, but you can't ignore the reality of the internet and how sites like SO work.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - updated my answer, any scripts are now omitted by default.

Comment: @vsync unfortunately, that doesn't do it, as is [explicitly documented](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) under "Security Considerations" - in fact - that img onerror thing is the first thing that any hacker would try. I don't think you have to show the OP how to defend against xss. Just mention that this technique might expose it and they should research it to verify whether it applies to them or not.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - I knew that prior to editing. Added a disclaimer for the poor souls who might somehow use an array from an unknown source and convert it to DOM and then inject it on their page.

Comment: @vsync -- do not suppose that the behavior you mock as only something "a poor soul" would do is any less common than rain on Sundays.  The only reason that XSS works is that programmers are not vigilant against it. "Fools attract predators, by being easy prey." —  Richard Adams

Comment: a fool developer would ignore DRY principle, a wise one will implement a security measurement in a higher level of the code, which wouldn't need to be repeated, as in this case. please go now and fix 10 million other answers in this website regarding generating DOM and make sure all of those also include XSS safty guard... it's out of the scope of the questions. answers are not articles which should cover every possible thing. I am against that approach.