# How to correctly name programmatically-created tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

As well all perfectly know, we can create new elements via the following code:

```
$('<div/>', {
  style: 'display: inline-block;'
})
```

But I wonder, is there any rules about how they should be created?

Should I pass as the first argument (the tag name) string like this -- `<div/>`? Or maybe like this -- `<div>`? Or even like this -- `div`?

It is unclear for me from the docs.

Comment: Any of them is fine, it's a personal preference. There's no real 'best' method here. See the docs for more examples: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2

Comment: Is difficult to say, every way appears to work with jQuery. This issue points a discussion about document.createElem‌​ent equivalent in jquery, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent

Comment: Your parsing html in a string, not creating an element based on a single node name argument, what you pass must be well formed.

Comment: What it the actual  problem you're having? Stack Overflow is not the berst forum for best practices, it's for actual problems you can't solve. `$('div')` will search for a div element, not create a new one

Comment: @AlexK. Note that it does allow a self closing div, even if that's not allowed by HTML

Comment: You can't use `div` imo. Because it is a selector for DOM elements. Or even if possible I would rather use `<div>` or `<div/>`, because it is better readable ...

Comment: _"When the parameter has a single tag (with optional closing tag or quick-closing) — $( "<img />" ) or $( "<img>" ), $( "<a></a>" ) or $( "<a>" ) — jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript .createElement() function."_ So all of those work fine. `$('div')` won't create elements though, it will select them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) is actually quite clear on that. It expects an [`htmlString`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString):

> A string is designated htmlString in jQuery documentation when it is used to represent one or more DOM elements, typically to be created and inserted in the document. When passed as an argument of the jQuery() function, the string is identified as HTML if it starts with ) and is parsed as such until the final > character.

So you cannot use `div` as that would actually search for all existing `<div>`s in your DOM.

And [it also says](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> When the parameter has a single tag (with optional closing tag or quick-closing) — $( "`<img />`" ) or $( "`<img>`" ), $( "`<a></a>`" ) or $( "`<a>`" ) — jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript .createElement() function.

There it clearly says that closing the tag is optional. So either of `<div>` or `<div />` are fine.