# Fade In and Fade Out Within a Search Interval Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a function that empties a div and inserts a random image from unsplash.com every six seconds using the setInterval function in jQuery. I would like to smooth out the transition using the fadeIn and fadeOut functions, but have been unable to successfully implement this. Below is my code:

```
function playImageSlideshow() {
  $("#image-slideshow").removeClass("display-none");
  $("#images").append("<img src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/" + currentCity + "'>");
  setInterval(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    $("#images").empty();
    $("#images").append("<img src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/" + currentCity + "/?" + date.getTime() + "'>");
  }, 6000);
}
```

Comment: If you're already using JQuery, use the API http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/.

Comment: Simply using a fadeOut before emptying the div and a fadeIn after appending the image does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `fadeIn` from jQuery.

First Create the `img` element as follow:

```
var $img = $("<img class='hide' src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/" + currentCity + "/?" + date.getTime() + "'>");
```

Then, call the faIn function:

```
$img.fadeIn()
```

That `img` is created with a class `hide` to hide it and then execute the fadeIn effect.  Another alternative is execute the `hide()` function before append this new elemento to your `DIV`, ie: `$img.hide()`.

## Look at this code snippet

```js
let currentCity = 'london';

function playImageSlideshow() {
  $("#image-slideshow").removeClass("display-none");
  $("#images").append("<img src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/" + currentCity + "'>");
  setInterval(function() {
    var date = new Date();

    var $images = $("#images");
    $("#images img").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $images.empty();

      var $img = $("<img class='hide' src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/" + currentCity + "/?" + date.getTime() + "'>");
      $images.append($img);

      $img.fadeIn(2000);
    });
  }, 3000);
}

playImageSlideshow();
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='images'></div>
```

See? now the transition is smoother.

## Resource

- [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)
- [jQuery document.createElement equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent)

Comment: how would you incorporate the fadeOut though? Whenever I've added it, the program skips over it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the JQuery API and update the image in the setTimeout.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $("#images").fadeOut(1000);
  $("#images").attr("src", "https://i2.wp.com/www.monicaperezcounseling.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/pexels-source-unsplash-4.jpg");
  $("#images").fadeIn(1000);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="images"/>
```