# How to escape string getting passed as parameter -- Invalid Syntax. Missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting this error when trying to use jquery append.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Here is my code:

```
$(".grid-uniform").append('<input type="checkbox" id="addToCompare-'+prod.id+'" class="addToCompare" onclick="addProductToCompare('+prod.id+','+prod.json.variants[0].id+','+prod.title+')">');
```

Here are the values being passed in:

```
addProductToCompare(1557908979773,13234446893117,Apple iPhone X - Zizo ION Triple Layered Hybrid Rugged Case with Tempered Glass, Smoke/Clear)
```

It looks like the 'with' in the string is getting picked up as JavaScript. It should just be a string. When I check typeof it returns string. If I swap prod.price instead of prod.title though and keep everything else the same, it works fine.

Comment: Wasn't this just posted in another question?

Comment: do not do it as  string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/jquery-document-createelement-equivalent

Comment: There was an error in the post that caused people to misinterpret it. As a result, no one was able to answer it, and it got erased. So I fixed the error and reposted.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you don't make the third argument a string literal, delimiting with quotes.

```
$(".grid-uniform").append(
    '<input type="checkbox" id="addToCompare-'+prod.id+'" class="addToCompare" ' +
    'onclick="addProductToCompare('+prod.id+','+prod.json.variants[0].id+',\''+prod.title+'\')">'
);
```

Note the added `\'` around the last argument.

The better way to do this:

```
$(".grid-uniform").append(
     $('<input>').attr({type: "checkbox", id: "addToCompare-"+prod.id})
         .addClass("addToCompare")
         .click(function () {
              addProductToCompare(prod.id, prod.json.variants[0].id, prod.title);
         })
);
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you leave a comment?