# Replace <i> elements with <span> elements

Tags: javascript, wordpress, accessibility, element

I want to replace all "i" elements with "span" elements.
I try many things but it didn't work.
I didn't find either error messages and debug JavaScript code in my browser.

I want to replace for example:

```
<i class="icon-user"></i>
```

to

```
<span class="icon-user"></span>
```

I try those but nothing works:

**1)**

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Replace <i> elements with <span> elements
    $('i.icon-user').replaceWith('<span class="icon-user"></span>');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

 <p>This is an icon <i class="icon-user"></i> and this as well <i class="icon-user"></i>
</p>
```

**2)**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Check if jQuery is loaded
  if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
    console.error('jQuery is not loaded.');
    return;
  }

  // Check if the element exists
  if ($('i.icon-user').length === 0) {
    console.error('The element with class "icon-user" does not exist.');
    return;
  }

  // Replace <i> with <span>
  $('i.icon-user').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<span class="icon-user"></span>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<p>This is an icon <i class="icon-user"></i> and this as well <i class="icon-user"></i>
</p>
```

**3)**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var iconUsers = document.querySelectorAll('i.icon-user');
  iconUsers.forEach(function(iconUser) {
    var spanElement = document.createElement('span');
    spanElement.className = 'icon-user';
    iconUser.parentNode.replaceChild(spanElement, iconUser);
  });
});
```

```html
<p>This is an icon <i class="icon-user"></i> and this as well <i class="icon-user"></i>
</p>
```

Comment: You want 1. Create https://stackoverflow.com/a/268507/2569323  2. Remove. 

Comment: Why did you tag this with `accessibility`? Are there any concerns regarding usability of these icons by users with disabilities? Why do you want to replace these `<i>` anyway? (:

Comment: How are you verifying that it doesn’t work, because all of your examples do work. I replaced the code with snippets to verify. If I inspect the icons with the browser’s developer tools, all the `<i>`  are replaced with `<span>`.

Answer (score 1):

[Not using JQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/), you can use [`Element.replaceWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith).

Here's an example.

```js
setTimeout(replaceIWithSpan, 1500);

function replaceIWithSpan() {
  document.querySelectorAll(`i.icon-user`)
  .forEach( i => {
    const span = document.createElement(`span`);
    // copy attributes from <i> to <span>
    for (const attr of i.attributes) {
      span.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value);
    }
    
    span.innerHTML = i.innerHTML;
    console.log(`${i.outerHTML} replaced with\n=> ${span.outerHTML}`);
    // replace
    i.replaceWith(span);
  });
}
```

```css
span.icon-user {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

i.icon-user {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div><i class="icon-user" id="el1">#1</i></div>
<div><i class="icon-user" id="el2">#2</i></div> 
<div><i class="icon-user" id="el3">#3</i></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the same. You can take a look [link](https://jobstoday.gr/) the file is in child theme "custom script".

Comment: @MichailKappas That's not how SO works. The example from the answer is a possible solution. It works here. If it doesn't work in the location where you need it, there must be something else wrong. No one can - and/or will not debug the site location. I advise you create an isolated [wordpress] page containing *only* the functionality you need and debug that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach utilizing regex to replace the tag name but keep its structure

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('i.icon-user').forEach(function(iconUser) {
    iconUser.outerHTML = iconUser.outerHTML.replace(/(?:(?<=^<)|(?=\w+>$))\b\w+\b/g, 'span')
  });

  console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<i class="icon-user"></i>
<div>
  <i id="foo" class="icon-user">
    <span>test</span>
  </i>
  <i class="bar"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

**The Script:**

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
      let a=$("<span></span>").addClass('icon-user').text('abc');
    a.replaceAll("i.icon-user");
    });
```

It works. Try and reply. Glad to help.

Comment: This won't replace all `i.icon-user` elements with `span` elements. Additionally, unused commented out code is distracting in an answer, and should not be included.